# Is there a single word that means "more informative"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Looking for one word that means "more informative" or "more clear", "better communicates" etc...

Comment: As others have noted, 1) these three are very different things, and without context your question is just too vague, 2) "clearer" is a rather obvious candidate, and 3) asking for a one-word comparative form of a four-syllable adjective is kind of pointless because the English grammar just does not work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with "clearer"?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "more informative" is not the same as "more clear" or "better communicates", so I am not sure what you are asking.

If your question were *clearer* I would understand it better.  If my answer gives you more information than another, it is "more informative" even if it is not any clearer.